# Inconsistent accessibility to a <List>

Tags: c#, list

I have the following error

> CS0053    Inconsistent accessibility: property type '`List<Koers>`' is less accessible than property '`DataStorage.deKoers`'

This issue is similar to other posts; yet i cannot find the proper solution:

- the class DataStorage has the public access modifier
- excluding the public modifier on deLijst or deKoers makes it inaccessable outside this class (and i want to access them)
- removing the public modifier from the DataStorage class solves the error message, but makes offcourse the properties not accessible from any other location

I suspect the List to play an unexpected role; as it works with the "MyText" property.

```
DataStorage instStorage = new DataStorage();
private void LadenInventarisVanDisk()
    {
        var x = instStorage.MyText;
        Console.WriteLine(x.ToString() );

    }


namespace Storage
{
    public class DataStorage
    {
        /* this works fine*/ 
        private string _myText = "text to save" ;
        public string MyText
        {
            get { return _myText; }
            set { _myText = value; }
        }

        private List<Inventaris>  _deLijst;

        /* adding public generate the accessible error*/
        public List<Inventaris> DeLijst
        {
            get { return _deLijst; }
            set { _deLijst = value; }
        }

        private List<Koers> _deKoers;
        /* excluding the public means i cannot call this property from another location */
        List<Koers> deKoers
        {
            get { return _deKoers; }
            set { _deKoers = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems odd - is this `List` the normal one from `System.Collections.Generic` or is this a custom class in your code? Normally I'd expect to see this error if `List` was a custom property that is private or internal which would mean your public property could be visible from outside the assembly but the `List` class couldn't...

Comment: The normal one: using System.Collections.Generic;  No special tricks applied.

Comment: That is very strange then. I assume you've actually confirmed that in the code rather than just going by what you *expect* it to be?

Comment: what are Koers and Inventaris? I'm assuming they are classes. if so, then make them public classes and then make the property as Public deKoers

Comment: Ah, I had been confused by your error message having been mangled and removing the generic parameter and forgot exactly how the error message works! I figured since the error message just mentioned `List` that it must be related to that. Be careful to use code markup (single backtick around text) so that the generic parameter doesn't get interpreted as HTML!

Comment: Try using `List<T>`'s fully qualified type name to check nothing weird is happening with ambigous namespaces. A stretch for sure, but this is a strange problem

Comment: On the list I am sure.  The problem was indeed that the underlying classes Koers and Inventaris were not public.

Comment: sorry for the confusion on the `<List>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is likely that the classes `Inventaris` and / or `Koers` are less accessible than public (default accessibility for classes is `internal` if in not nested and `private` if nested.) Both are more restrictive than public and will raise the error). A good way to fix this is always explicitly writing the access level for everything - it makes these kind of bugs easier to see

Answer (score 4):

The accessibility of a `List<T>` is determined by the accessibility of a given `T`, therefore your classes `Koers` and `Inventaris` have to be publicly accessible for a `List<Koers` / `List<Inventaris>` to be returned by your properties, as a property cannot be more visible than the object that it is returning.

See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0053) for another examle.

So your classes have to be declared like this:

```
public class Koers
{
    //Class code here
}

public class Inventaris
{
    //Class code here
}
```

EDIT: As suggested by Chris, I clarified my answer a bit.

Comment: Your first sentence isn't quite right. They have to be public to be returned by a *public* property. You could have a less visible property (eg private) and they would be valid. The key thing is that the property cannot be more visible than the object that it is returning and in this case a `List<T>` is only as visible as the `T`.